# How to search CPT's by meta query from the admin dashboard?

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, search

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious, but I've looked and can't figure this out. I have a CPT (`request_form`) and I need to perform searches on meta queries (wp_postmeta) rather than the post title. The catch is I need to do this from the admin dashboard and my code isn't working. I've done similar kinds of searches on the user side, but not the admin side before. I figured `pre_get_posts` was the right hook to use, but I'm getting nowhere.

Two strange things I noticed.

1. `meta_query` is present twice in the `$query` object. Once at `$query->query_vars['meta_query']` and once at `$query->meta_query`.
2. When I enable `SAVEQUERIES` in `wp-config.php` and dump `$wpdb->queries`, I don't see my query being executed at all.

   ```
   function my_search($query) {
     if (!is_admin()) {
       return;
     }

    if ($query->query['post_type'] !== 'request_form') {
      return;
    }

    if (!$query->is_search) {
     return $query;
    }

    $search = $query->query_vars['s'];

    $meta_query = array(
       'relation' => 'OR',
       array(
         'key' => 'request_details',
         'value' => $search,
         'compare' => 'LIKE'
       ),
       array(
         'key' => 'request_subject',
         'value' => $search,
         'compare' => 'LIKE'
       )
     );

     $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
     echo "<pre>";
     var_dump($query);
     echo "</pre>";

     return $query;
   }
   add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_search');
   ```

If I query directly in the db using sequelpro with the follwing, I get back exactly the posts I expect (sorry, I know this isn't exactly the same).

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value LIKE "%basketball%"
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the Query Monitor plugin to see what actual query that is being executed when you perform a search.

I suspect the problem you are having is that you are not unsetting the initial query vars.  You are adding the meta query, but you haven't removed the s= parameter, which only searches for your keyword in the title, content and excerpt.

Below  `$query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);`, try adding either of these: `$query->set('s', '');` to set 's' to an empty string or `$query->__unset('s');` to unset it.

Comment: that was it exactly! thank you so much :-) these particular CPT's are generated from ACF. so there's essentially no `content` or `excerpt` and the title is being overridden by an administrator after the form is submitted.

Comment: Just to add to this, worked by adding the following after $query->set() - $query->query['s'] = $query->query_vars['s'] = '';